# How can I render two JSX variables conditionally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, rendering

I've got two JSX variables and I need to render them conditionally.
These are my variables:

```
 const example1= (<div className="row">
             <p>TEST1</p>
             </div>);
 const example2= (<div className="row">
             <p>TEST1</p> 
             </div>);
```

I need to render example1 and then example1 && example2

How can I do it in JSX??

This one works.

```
{this.state.input === "1" && example1}
```

This one doesn't work

```
{this.state.input === "2" && example1 && example2}
{this.state.input === "2" ? (example1 && example2) : null}
```

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{this.state.input === "1" && example1}
{this.state.input === "2" && (
  <React.Fragment>
    {example1}
    {example2}
  </React.Fragment>
)}
```

If you prefer, you can use `<> </>` as a shorthand for `<React.Fragment> </React.Fragment>`

Comment: There was a way using Fragment with import from import React, {Fragment} from 'react'; and using <Fragment></Fragment>
Do you remember how to do that

Answer (score 1):

if you want to show both try this

```
{this.state.input === "2" ? <>{example1}{example2}</> : ""}
```